# Laravel error while sending a queue email

Tags: php, laravel

I'm facing the following error in the `failed_jobs` database table:

> ErrorException: Undefined property: stdClass::$subscription in
> /home/sm/public_html/app/Mail/NewCustomer.php:45

This is pretty basic. It means the property `$subscription` does not exists, but...the problem is that I don't call `$subscription` anywhere in the class code.

In the controller I assign the values:

```
$to = ['email' => 'someemail@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Name test'];

$mail = new \stdClass;
$mail->to = $to;
$mail->subject = 'Subject test';
$mail->body = 'Body test';

\Mail::queue(new \App\Mail\NewCustomer($mail));
```

And the NewCustomer class contains:

```
namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewCustomer extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Holds the item content
     * 
     * @var Array
     */
    protected $item;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     * 
     * @param Array
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($item)
    {
        $this->item = $item;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        $this->to($this->item->to['email'], $this->item->to['name'])
            ->subject($this->item->subject)
            ->view('mails/new_customer')
            ->with('item', $this->item);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

The view `mails/new_customer` also does not contain anything related with `$subscription`.

Is this some cache problem or something? I can't figure out where the variable `$subscription` comes from.

If instead of Queue I send the email immediately, it works great:

```
\Mail::send(new \App\Mail\NewCustomer($mail));
```

Comment: could you add your mail view?

Comment: it may be a cache problem so try to run `php artisan queue:reload`

Comment: @Joseph it worked. I tried before to clear the cache, but I don't remember exactly what commands did I use. Btw, it's not `queue:reload` but yes `queue:restart` (at least for me).

Comment: yah it is `queue:restart` you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

It was indeed a cache problem. Run `php artisan queue:restart` in terminal or through laravel:

```
\Artisan::call('queue:restart');
```